# React-native: add a component to all the screens created via react-navigation and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm creating a react-native app with react-navigation and redux to manage the state. This is my app.js file:

```
// all the imports...

const store = createStore(combineReducers({ store: Store}));

const ProfileScreenStore = connect(state => ({ store: state.store}))(ProfileScreen);
const SensingScreenStore = connect(state => ({ store: state.store }))(SensingScreen);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: ProfileScreenStore,
    Sensing: SensingScreenStore,
    SensingTarget: SensingTargetScreen,
    Navigation: NavigationScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Profile"
  }
);

const Navigation = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I would like to add an `Error` component so I can display error messages in all the screen of the application. My idea is to do something like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Error />
        <Navigation />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

But when I do that I get the error message:

```
>  TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
>
>  This error is located at:
>     in Error (at App.js:40)
>     in Provider (at App.js:38)
>     in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>     in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:45)
>     in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
>     in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

How can I fix the error?

EDIT: as requested, here's the content of `Error.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Error extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{this.props.store.error.message}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: fix the error triggered

Comment: Can we see the content of `Error.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems seems to come from the `Error.js` component that tries to access `this.props.store` while `this.props` is undefined.

You probably want to connect the component to the Redux store to get access to the error message. Something like:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { message: state.error.message };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Error);
```

where `state.error.message` is defined in your reducer.

Then you can just use `this.props.message` to display the error message.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to connect the store to the error component!